# After IF in foreach remove item from array! php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

In my foreach loop I want the item that comes in the IF not te be outputted anymore after the if statement. It keeps coming back... How can I fix this?

```
$content1 = "";

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($brandnid)) {
        $content1 .= ',"' . $key . '":{"und":[{"nid":"[nid:' . $value . ']"}]}';
        unset($array[array_search('field_brandid',$array)]);
    }
    $content1 .= ',"' . $key . '":{"und":[{"value":"' . $value . '"}]}';
}

if(!empty($title) && !empty($day) && !empty($month) && !empty($year)) {
    $postContent = '{"type":"carmodels","title":"' . $title . '"' . $content1 . ',"field_modelyear":{"und":[{"value":{"date":"' . $dateBuild . '"}}]}}';
}elseif(!empty($day) && !empty($month) && !empty($year)) {
    $postContent = '{"type":"carmodels","field_modelyear":{"und":[{"value":{"date":"' . $dateBuild . '"}}]}' . $content1 . '}';
}else {
    $postContent = '{"type":"carmodels"' . $content1 . '}';
}
```

In above case I entered fields color (normal field) and the brandid and it displays the following in $postContent:

```
{"type":"carmodels","field_modelcolor":{"und":[{"nid":"[nid:black]"}]},"field_modelcolor":{"und":[{"value":"black"}]},"field_brandid":{"und":[{"nid":"[nid:24]"}]},"field_brandid":{"und":[{"value":"24"}]}}
```

But it should only do the brandid in the if statement (once) and after that the normal field which doesnt reach the IF also once

Comment: Never try and remove items from the array you are `foreach`ing over. There be dragons. Make a copy of the array and remove items from that, then make that your new array once the process is completed

Comment: How can I fix it then to only display that item once in the foreach after it has been in the if? and just display the other items (minus the one in the if) outside the if?

Comment: Also if you want to build JSON data, build it in PHP classes/arrays and then use `json_encode()` to turn that into a `json` string.

Comment: I totally don't understand the logic of "if (!empty($brandnid))". What is $brandnid? Is it mistyped $brandid? Where do you get it from? The if() will work every time the $brandnid is not empty. You don't change it in the shown code so if it is not empty, it'll stay non-empty forever. Also I don't see why you ever need to remove an entry from the array, because it doesn't affect any output.

Comment: the brandnid (nid for drupal) it entered but I didn't include it in the code above.

Comment: The way I want it is that it adds that line in the if statement to the $content1 variable. And after that (for example if entered ($color which is also in the array then) enter that line once in $content1

Comment: If you wanna display one key only once in a while, then you can create one Temp Array with unique Keys and use that Array in for-each loop.